# C++ class template method for varied parameter types

Tags: c++

I am wrapping some sqlite stuff and I was wondering if, maybe using templates, I could avoid having to wrap each type with a new method. However, I am absolutely lost, fumbling around with templates. I cannot find a great tutorial.

This is what my Statement class looks like right now

```
class Statement {
  public:
    Statement();
    ~Statement();
    void BindInt(int index, int value);
    void BindInt(std::string name, int value);
    void BindInt64(int index, int value);
    void BindInt64(std::string name, int value);
    void BindText(int index, std::string value);
    void BindText(std::string name, std::string value);
};
Statement::Statement(){}
Statement::~Statement(){}
void Statement::BindInt(int index, int value){}
void Statement::BindInt(std::string name, int value){}
void Statement::BindInt64(int index, int value){}
void Statement::BindInt64(std::string name, int value){}
void Statement::BindText(int index, std::string value){}
void Statement::BindText(std::string name, std::string value){}
```

I feel like I could write something else that is generic, like

```
  class Statement {
      public:
        Statement();
        ~Statement();
        template<class T, class V>
        void Bind(T param, V value);
    };
    Statement::Statement(){}
    Statement::~Statement(){}
    template<class T, class V>
    void Statement::Bind(T index, T value){}
```

But I would need to know what type of value was passed in `value` so I can call the correct underlying function, eg `sqlite_bind_int` or `sqlite_bind_text`, etc. Is this possible?

Comment: @user463035818 Oh... that makes so much more sense. I overthought this. :|

Comment: @user463035818 You get a slightly nicer interface to your class IMO, but templates certainly don't lead to simpler code in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I would need to know what type of value was passed in value ....

You do know the type. It is `V`.

> ... so I can call the correct underlying function, eg sqlite_bind_int or
>   sqlite_bind_text, etc. Is this possible?

If you need to call a different method for each type passed as `value` you wont gain much from using templates. You would end up writing a specialization for each possible type to call the corresponding `sqlite_bind_XY` function. You can get the same much easier with overloads:

```
class Statement {
  public:
    Statement();
    ~Statement();        
    void Bind(int index, int value);               // aka BindInt
    void Bind(std::string name, int value);
    void Bind(int index, int64_t value);           // aka BindInt64
    void Bind(std::string name, int64_t value);    
    void Bind(int index, std::string value);       // aka BindText
    void Bind(std::string name, std::string value);
};
```

Note that I had to change `int` to `int64_t` to make them different. You would have the same issue with templates. Sometimes there is no obvious way to make the parameters different, then you can use tags:

```
class Statement {
  public:
    struct text_tag{};
    struct int_tag{};
    struct int64_tag{};
    Statement();
    ~Statement();        
    void Bind(int_tag,int index, int value);               // aka BindInt
    void Bind(int_tag,std::string name, int value);
    void Bind(int64_tag,int index, int value);           // aka BindInt64
    void Bind(int64_tag,std::string name, int value);    
    void Bind(text_tag,int index, std::string value);       // aka BindText
    void Bind(text_tag,std::string name, std::string value);
};
```

As a super simplified rule of thumb to be taken with a grain of salt: when you want to do something different for each type use overloads when you want to do the same for each type use templates.

PS: as pointed out by @Mils Budnek "You get a slightly nicer interface to your class IMO, but templates certainly don't lead to simpler code in this case." I do agree, but concentrated on advocating overloads ;).

Comment: Interesting funfact: If you think the question is worth answering, it's probably worth upvoting, even if for no better reason than the upvote makes the question harder to delete.

Comment: @user4581301 i dont think upvotes are related to how easy a question can get closed, are they? Sometimes while I write an answers the question gets closed or deleted, just wanted to avoid that.

Comment: [Wouldn't have been the first time I've been wrong, so I just looked it up.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222) I may well be wrong. Regardless, this struck me a s a good, well-posed question so I upvoted it.

Comment: A downside to Miles' point is the apparent availability of the template may fool some into believing that <type of choice> is supported by the template when it is not. This'll get caught by the linker or SFINAE, but I think a well formed API should describe what you can do with it and  in this case the template approach breaks that thinking.

Comment: @user4581301 not sure, I am a bloody newbie on templates myself, my strategy is: either the template is fine with the type or the compiler will tell you. Also in the standard library, trying to instantiate invalid templates is still a nice way of getting in touch with implementation details (take `std::vector<int,double> a;` as a random example). Maybe things will change radically with concepts but I know close to zero about them

Comment: Same boat, really. I come from C and work with C programmers. They freak out when I use templates as more than generics, so I've never gotten any real-world practice in the arcane arts. As for the failure being caught, it will. But  A) this might be after the programmer has designed their program based on a faulty assumption and started writing and B) the error might be a cryptic time-waster.